# Sublime Text 3 fails to open SumatraPDF

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, pdf-viewer

I am using a Windows 7 machine with most recent Sublime Text 3 Build 3013. SumatraPDF is properly inbound as user and system PATH variable: (...\;C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF)

Now I am trying to get LaTeX running with Sublime Text 3. It can compile a PDF, however, SumatraPDF does not open via Sublime (I can manually start and open the PDF that has been complied just before in SumatraPDF).

```
Welcome to thread Thread-5
['latexmk', '-cd', '-e', '-f', '-pdf', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', 'neu.tex']
Finished normally
0
False True True

!TEX root =  'C:\\Users\\Jens\\Desktop\\Arbeit\\Jens\\Sublime\\neu.tex'
Jump to:  9 14
Windows, Calling Sumatra
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 568, in run_
      return self.run(edit, **args)
      File "C:\Users\Jens\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\LaTeXTools\jumpToPDF.py", line 233, in run
      subprocess.Popen(startCommands, startupinfo = si)
      File "./subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
      File "./subprocess.py", line 1118, in _execute_child

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

My settings of LaTeX tools is:

```
"windows": {
    // Path used when invoking tex & friends; "" is fine for MiKTeX
    // For TeXlive 2011 (or other years) use
    // "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2011\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
    "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2015\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
    // TeX distro: "miktex" or "texlive"
    "distro" : "texlive",
    // Command to invoke Sumatra. If blank, "SumatraPDF.exe" is used (it has to be on your PATH)
    "sumatra": "",
    // Command to invoke Sublime Text. Used if the keep_focus toggle is true.
    // If blank, "subl.exe" or "sublime_text.exe" will be used.
    "sublime_executable": "",
    // how long (in seconds) to wait after the jump_to_pdf command completes
    // before switching focus back to Sublime Text. This may need to be
    // adjusted depending on your machine and configuration.
    "keep_focus_delay": 0.5
},
```

Can you give an advice? This thread ([Sublime Text 2 LatexTools not launching SumatraPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493121/sublime-text-2-latextools-not-launching-sumatrapdf)) feels similar, but I properly set the PATH variable in my case.

Edit: Added this one in respect to comment.

```
import os; os.environ['PATH']
```

> > 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\'

Comment: Is there actually a space in your `%PATH%` variable before `C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF`? If so, could you remove it?

Comment: Yes, there was a space, I removed it, but it did not help.

Comment: From the Sublime console (**View | Console**) could you run `import os; os.environ['PATH']`?

Comment: Yes, added it in answer, and thanks for support so far!

Comment: Can you just try changing the "sumatra" setting to C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"? That should at least force things to work...

Comment: This is not working either. Error report does not change.

Comment: Do you perhaps have the 32-bit version of Sumatra on a 64-bit system (which would be installed in c:\program files (x86)\sumstrapdf?

Comment: I changed it (had 64-bit, but installed under program files)...

Error...['latexmk', '-cd', '-e', '-f', '-pdf', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', 'neu.tex']
Finished normally
0
False True True
!TEX root =  'C:\\Users\\Jens\\Desktop\\Arbeit\\Jens\\Sublime\\neu.tex'
Jump to:  9 14
Windows, Calling Sumatra
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

Comment: Now I fixed in in following way: changing folder to program files (x86) [despite I had a 64-bit installed in program folders before) and removing the SumatraPDF.exe part from C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF. Restarted Sublime Text, and it worked. Do you want to write an answer, so I can tick it? Thanks for input!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out to be a `%PATH%` issue. SumatraPDF was installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF rather than C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF.